# checking for both true or both false

Tags: java, comparison, logic

if I have the following logic to check for both true or both false but ignore the others, I write:

```
if (a) {
  if (b) {
    // do something when both true
  }
} else if (!b) {
  // do something when both false
}
```

is that the simplest you can write in java?

of course I can write

```
if (a && b) {
    // do something when both true
} else if (!a && !b) {
  // do something when both false
}
```

but I am thinking if it is possible to achieve this using only one if condition and else without condition, e.g.

```
if (some condition) {
    // do something when both true
} else {  // <-- check! only else, no more condition
  // do something when both false
}
```

Impossible is of course an acceptable answer to this question (if accompanied with explanation)

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apologies for my initial XOR answer - I had misread your question. The correct answer is,

> > It is impossible in Java.

The reason is one of Boolean logic. When you have two logicals, A and B, then there are four possible states:

```
A  B
0  0    << A and B are false
0  1
1  0
1  1    << A and B are true
```

When you have a condition that says "Both A and B are true", you have just the last state. Unfortunately, the "else" (all the others) contains three possible states. You cannot have something that is true for one state, false for another, and "something else" for the other two. That's not how Boolean algebra works.

Comment: No, I need both are TRUE and then both are FALSE

Comment: So no matter how complex the first if condition I can write, there is no way to filter out the others by a simple else?

Comment: Indeed - because the first condition can only be true for one of the four possible states and all the other states are passed to the `else`. No getting around that.

Comment: @user1589188 `if (x) { .. } else { .. }` is semantically equivalent to `if (x) { .. } else if (!x) { .. }` (but don't write it like this!) where the expression `x` does not have a side-effect (and there is no further conditional chaining).

Comment: Sorry by post it at 2015, but in Java doesn't possible make a double comparison? For what I understand, OP wants that `a` and `b` is both `false` or both `true`. So `true+true` is true, `false+false` is true, `true+false` and versa is `false`. In this case, in Java, can I do something like `(a == expectedA) == (b == expectedB)`, not? **Explaining**: if the first comparison result match with second comparison result, it is validated.

Comment: OP wants to something different when both are false - otherwise XOR would have worked.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is **no**. You can't have an `else` clause that runs only under certain conditions without using an `else if`. An `else` clause without `else if` will run every time the condition in the `if` clause is false. If you want to add additional constraints (such as both `a` and `b` are false) you need to use an `else if`.

There is nothing wrong with using `else if` though, and it makes your intention fairly clear:

```
if (a && b) {

} else if (!a && !b) {

}
```

Comment: +1 For explanation. I think this is most simple/clear way. I'd use it *or* the variation: `if (a && b) { .. } else if (!(a || b)) { .. }`, depending on which I thought was more clear for the given case .. but it's also the same as given in the original post.

Answer (score 2):

You have three states you wish to handle differently -- though one case is to "do nothing."

```
if ( a && b )
{
    // Do something when both are true.
}
else if ( ! a && ! b )
{
    // Do something if both are false.
}
```

This is the most economical way to do what you want to achieve -- two tests for three cases.

Alternatively, if you can return 0 or 1 from your "boolean values" or your expressions, you could do something like:

```
switch ( a + b )
{
    case 0:
        // Do something when both a and b are "false."
        break;

    case 1:
        // Do something -- or nothing -- when a or b are "false" and the other is "true."
        break;

    case 2:
        // Do something when both a and b are "true."
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The following works for my case.

```java
if (!(a^b)) {
  // do something when both true or both false
} else {
  // do something when a and b are mismatch
}
```

Comment: This answer definitely suits in here because it answers exactly what the the title asks for, which is actually a more interesting question than the body.